# Encountering "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'join')" error in REST API despite not using join method

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use fields in my REST API to allow users to get only certain fields from a resource but for some reason when I test it with postman I get this error even if I'm not using the join method.

```
{
    "message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'join')"
}
```

This is how I'm passing the fields array to my transformer function

```
app.get("/api/fetchrecipes/:query", async (req, res) => {
  const query = req.params.query;
  const fields = req.query.fields ? req.query.fields.split(",") : null;
  ...
});
```

And this is my transformer function

```
module.exports.transformMealDb = function (data, fields) {
  return data.meals.map((meal) => {
    let transformedMeal = {};

    if (!fields || fields.includes('name')) {
      transformedMeal.name = meal.strMeal;
    }
    if (!fields || fields.includes('cuisine')) {
      transformedMeal.cuisine = meal.strArea;
    }
    if (!fields || fields.includes('diet')) {
      transformedMeal.diet = meal.strCategory;
    }
    if (!fields || fields.includes('prep_time')) {
      transformedMeal.prep_time = null; // Placeholder as prep_time is not available
    }
    if (!fields || fields.includes('ingredients')) {
      transformedMeal.ingredients = Array.from({ length: 20 }, (_, i) => {
        if (meal[`strIngredient${i + 1}`]) {
          return `${meal[`strIngredient${i + 1}`]} (${
            meal[`strMeasure${i + 1}`] || ""
          })`;
        }
        return null;
      }).filter(Boolean);
    }
    if (!fields || fields.includes('instructions')) {
      transformedMeal.instructions = meal.strInstructions.split("\r\n").filter(Boolean);
    }
    if (!fields || fields.includes('image')) {
      transformedMeal.image = meal.strMealThumb;
    }

    return transformedMeal;
  });
};
```

I tried checking if the fields array was effectively an array and it was being passed correctly to the function.

Comment: Are you using `.join()` somewhere in your code?

Comment: @NickParsons I am, but it has nothing to do with my function. I even tried to comment it out but I still get the same error.

Comment: It is supposedly a message from the API. You should inspect the server side (API) code.